# Showing that $10!=6!7!$ via Gamma function

Tags: integration, factorial, gamma-function

It is well-known that $10! = 6! 7! $, I want to prove it via algebraic manipulations of Gamma function, i.e show that:
 $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^7 e^{-x} \, dx \int_{0}^{+\infty} y^6 e^{-y} \, dy = \int_{0}^{+\infty} z^{10} e^{-z} \, dz \qquad (1) $$
I tried to write the LHS as:

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} \int_{0}^{+\infty} x (xy)^6 e^{-(x+y)}  \, dx dy \qquad (2)$$

and go for the substitution $u = x + y $, $v=xy$, but that leads to complicated calculations. Is there a reasonable way/substitution to turn the double integral in $(2)$ into the RHS in $(1)$. Thanks in advance for any contribution.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to integrate by part several times and use the identity $10!=6!7!$...

Comment: Use the identity you want to prove, well that sounds promising. xD

Comment: I would try use this identity that seems easier to manipulate $$\frac1{\Gamma(z)}=ze^{\gamma z}\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z}k\right)e^{-z/k}$$ for $z\in\Bbb C{\setminus}({-}\Bbb N)$.

Comment: Nice suggestion, I'll give it a thought and maybe edit the post, thank you :)

Comment: Isn't it possible to use B (beta) integrals ?

Comment: I tried to give a look at Beta function's most famous identities, but was not able to do much...

Comment: have you tried polar coordinates?

Comment: Normally, conversion of two $\Gamma$-function integrals into a single integral is the way to derive the Beta-function identity: $\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n) = \Gamma(m+n) B(m,n)$.  You can set your $x=u^2$, $y=v^2$, then change from $(u,v)$ to polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$.  The $r$-integral will become $\Gamma(m+n)$ and the $\theta$ integral the Beta function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal as I understand it is to use some nifty change of variables to turn this double integral
$$
LHS=\int_{0}^{+\infty} \int_{0}^{+\infty} x (xy)^6 e^{-(x+y)}  \, dx dy=6!\times 7!,
$$
into 
$$
RHS=\int_0^{+\infty} z^{10} e^{-z} \, dz=10!.
$$
This appears to me to be an exercise in manipulating the product of Gamma functions or as it is otherwise known a Beta function. A common substitution made when dealing with such a double integral turns the exponential weighting into a Gaussian
$$
x=s^2 , \ y=t^2 , \ \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (s,t)}=4st,
\\LHS=\int_{0}^{+\infty} \int_{0}^{+\infty} x (xy)^6 e^{-(x+y)}  \, dx dy=4\int_{0}^{+\infty} \int_{0}^{+\infty} s^2 (st)^{13} e^{-(s^2+t^2)}  \, ds dt. 
$$
This particular substitution is valuable because it makes it simpler to use the polar parametrization of the integration region which is desirable because it reduces the Gaussian weight function to single variable dependence 
$$
s=r\cos{(\theta)} ,\ t=r\sin{(\theta)} , \ \frac{\partial (s,t)}{\partial (r,\theta)}=r,
\\LHS=4\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-r^2}  \, r^{29}dr\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{15}{(\theta)} \sin^{13}{(\theta)} d\theta. 
$$
The $\theta$-integral is easily evaluated using the trigonometric substitution we all learn in high school
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{15}{(\theta)} \sin^{13}{(\theta)} \ d\theta
\\=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{14}{(\theta)} (1-\cos^{2}{(\theta)})^6\cos{(\theta)}\sin{(\theta)} \ du,
\\u=\cos^{2}{(\theta)} , \ \frac{du}{d\theta}=-2\cos{(\theta)}\sin{(\theta)},
\\=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} u^7 (1-u)^6 \ du=1/48048.
$$
Finally, the radial integral may be shown to be proportional to the RHS by using the first substitution I introduced and integrating by parts
$$
r=\sqrt{z} , \ \frac{dr}{dz}=\frac{1}{2}z^{-1/2} ,
\\\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-r^2}  \, r^{29}dr=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-z}  \, z^{14} dz=\frac{14\times13\times12\times11}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-z}  \, z^{10} dz,
$$
hence
$$
LHS=\frac{4\times14\times13\times12\times11}{2\times48048}\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-z}  \, z^{10} dz=\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-z}  \, z^{10} dz=RHS.
$$
As required, however it is worth noting that the quickest way to prove this identity is to simply use the definition of factorial and cancel down
$$
LHS=6!7!=\frac{6\times5\times4\times3\times2}{8\times9\times10}10!=10!=RHS.
$$
Unsurprisingly this is mirrored by using integration by parts on the integral representation of the Gamma function.

Comment: My answer is what jcandy Oct 20 at 8:09 proposed.

Comment: Very nice work :)

Comment: Yes, this is elegant.  For an alternative view of the origin of this nontrivial factorial product, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3916909/248217), in which an arithmetic progression uniquely embodied in  the 3-4-5 right triangle leads to the factorial product.