# Are these the only solutions to $a!b!=c!$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, factorial

Curious about [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2229096/showing-that-10-67-via-gamma-function) on, 
$$6!7!=10!\tag1$$
a little *Mathematica* expt yielded,
$$r!(r!-1)!=(r!)!\tag2$$

> Q: Are the only non-trivial integer solutions to $\color{blue}{a!b!=c!}$ with $a,b>1$ given by $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Comment: A related topic: [Factorial products](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialProducts.html)

Comment: Oops. Mea culpa. :/